# Schedule timers in background

Tags: swift, timer, notifications, background

I'm developing an application with a very important flow moment. Is saving data every **x** sec in the foreground and background. I know that timer runs not long so I've added:

1. Bg task on entering background
2. Wake up the suspended app every **x** hours

Here is the code:

```
class BackgroundTimer {

    private var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = .invalid
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var wakeUpTimer: Timer?

    init() {
        addNotifications()
        startTimer()
        startWakeUpTimer()
    }

    // MARK: Notifications

    private func addNotifications() {
        removeNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(applicationDidEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }

    private func removeNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc private func applicationDidEnterBackground() {
        stopBackgroundTask()
        startBackgroundTask()
    }

    @objc private func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
        stopBackgroundTask()
    }

    // MARK: Timer

    public func startTimer() {
        stopForegroundTask()
        startForegroundTask()
    }

    private func fireTimer(_ timer: Timer) {

        // Run code every 30 sec
        // here
        // -----------

        stopBackgroundTask()
        startBackgroundTask()
    }

    private func startForegroundTask() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true, block: fireTimer)
    }

    private func stopForegroundTask() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    // MARK: Background task

    private func startBackgroundTask() {

        guard timer != nil else { return }

        let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
        guard ((state == .background || state == .inactive) && bgTask == .invalid) else { return 
    }

        bgTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: { [weak self] in
            self?.stopBackgroundTask()
        })
    }

    private func stopBackgroundTask() {

        guard bgTask != .invalid else { return }

        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask)
        bgTask = .invalid
    }

    // MARK: Wake up timer

    private func startWakeUpTimer() {

        let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(4 * 3600)
        let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(fireWakeUpTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
    }

    @objc private func fireWakeUpTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
        startWakeUpTimer()
    }
}
```

But, as usually, something works not good. The timer can be stopped or wake up timer did not start.
Do you had same experience? How I can improve functionality?